# What happens if I tell my target I'm part of the Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know if there are any different outcomes based on how you handle an assassination for the Dark Brotherhood. I usually kill outright without any prior contact but during my last assignment, I engaged the target in conversation. There were two possible options: "So and so sent me and they are angry" and "I'm part of the Dark Brotherhood, I'm going to kill you."

So what happens if I talk to them first? If I tell them I'm part of the Dark Brotherhood, do they try to bribe me? If I reveal that an angry person sent me, do I receive the option of helping them work it out as opposed to murder? I'm just curious about all the outcomes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, they'll attack you.

This can make the assassination quite a bit easier, since you are technically acting in "self defense", and you will not be given a bounty for killing the target. You will also not draw aggro from otherwise neutral NPCs in the area, like you would if they noticed you attacking the target in the first place.

Comment: I just used this tactic and it worked amazingly even in a room full of guards. Thanks!

Comment: You also won't get a bounty if you ask a companion to do your dirty work for you. The guards will attack them for a bit but then stop.

Comment: @Annan How do I tell my companion to do it? Is there a dialogue option for it? Because this is a great idea!

Comment: @spugsley If you talk to your companion one of the conversation options is asking them to do something. You can then ask them to walk places, pick up items, pick locks, stand on traps and attack people. (just move the cursor over the object when in command mode)

Comment: ^Also, one of the wikis says "guards will find you responsible for crimes that your followers commit"! However I have not found this the case, at least with assassinations.